# How make this iframe code work where to set the website url?

Tags: iframe

I found this code from stackoverflow but how can use it - i meant specifically where do i enter the source url on the iframe code in order for it to run? I am completely noob in Javascript so please bear with me. For example lets say i want to iframe source = https://google.com where should i put it?

```js
<script>
(function(d){
  var iframe = d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('iframe')),
  doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

  // style the iframe with some CSS
  iframe.style.cssText = "position:absolute;width:200px;height:100px;left:0px;";

  doc.open().write('<body onload="' + 
  'var d = document;d.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].' + 
  'appendChild(d.createElement(\'script\')).src' + 
  '=\'\/path\/to\/file\'">');

  doc.close(); //iframe onload event happens

  })(document);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to iframe another site into yours you could just do

```
<iframe src="https://google.com"></iframe>
```

without any javascript.

Take a look at [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) for more info.

Comment: Actually I know how to use the simple iframe but I want to use the code as in question